# What parameters help to decide when to use which : Thread or ThreadPool or Task in C#

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I would like to know in which all scenarios and situation one should use a `Thread` class, a `ThreadPool` class or `Task Parallel Library` and what is the difference between them.

I tried to find this by googling but could not find anything.

I am asking this as there may be certain scenarios in which using `Thread` class and managing Threads ourselves is better and other scenarios in which `ThreadPool` would be better but not quite sure about those.

e.g. We want to load large volumes of Order data from database on application startup: What Thread Management technique (Thread | ThreadPool | TPL) would provide optimal benefits and would also provide a more code maintainability and other benefits.

**Above is just one example, but I would like to specifically know *what all parameters* to consider in the threading scenarios that *can help deciding* between usage of `Thread` OR `ThreadPool` OR `TPL`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I would recommend always using `Task` or `Task<T>` in code targeting .NET 4 or later.

This provides a unified API which gives you the benefit of using the ThreadPool by default (but allowing you to use custom schedulers or specify the `LongRunning` hint, which, by default creates a dedicated thread).  In addition, it future proofs your code, as moving forward with C# 5 you gain the advantages of being able to integrate with the new async language support when appropriate.

The problem with using `Thread` or the `ThreadPool` classes directly is that they do not contain methods for composing multiple work items, at least not directly.  `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` will take advantage of the thread pool, but this also happens (by default) with `Task.Factory.StartNew`.  However, the resulting `Task` allows easy composition with other tasks (`Tasks.WaitAll`, continuations, etc), that allows for much more expressive composition of multiple work items.

The TPL also provides the benefits of directly working with and supporting the [cancellation model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) in the framework.

Comment: ok, that's a good suggestion but if you can also explain why Task or Task<T> is better?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you should use `Task`s, as Reed explains in his answer.

But there are some rare situations when you want to have a control over the thread(s) you're creating. This includes when you want to set:

- thread priority
- apartment state (some COM objects require this)
- processor affinity (this should be very rare)

In those cases you should use `Thread` directly (and certainly not for example modify the priority of a thread pool thread). Though you can combine this with TPL and for example create a `TaskScheduler` that runs its `Task`s on a `Thread` with appartment state set to STA.